# Finding the Baye's Estimator

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

The likelihood for a single observation is $f(x|\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}$ and the prior distribution is a $gamma(4, \lambda)$ so the distribution is 
$\frac{\lambda^{4}}{6}\theta^{3}e^{\lambda\theta}$

$f(\theta)f(x|\theta)=\frac{\lambda^4}{6}\theta^2e^{-\lambda\theta}$

The next step would be to integrate this from x to infinity.
$$\int_x^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^4}{6}\theta^3e^{-\lambda\theta} d \theta$$

To find $f(x)$.

The problem is I do not know how to integrate this.

Comment: Integration by-parts will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you are looking for the posterior distribution of $\theta$, so you do not have to worry about $f(x)$

That is: 
$$
f(\theta~|~x)\varpropto f(~x ~|~\theta~)~f(\theta)=\frac{\lambda^4}{6}\theta^2e^{-\lambda\theta}~\varpropto~\theta^2e^{-\lambda~\theta}
$$

You can see that this is just the kernel of the Gamma( 3 , $\lambda$ ):

$$
f(\theta|x)~\varpropto~ \theta^{(3-1)}e^{-\lambda~\theta}
$$

Which is the same result you  will get by finding the distribution of x, generally we don't really care about it though as it is just there for normalization (to ensure that that the result will integrate to 1). Things get a lot faster by spotting kernels. Otherwise you can just solve by integrating by parts (much more tedious).

Hope this helps